# Pagination issue of Bootstrap data-tables

Tags: datatables

I am using bootstrap for better look and feel of UI, my issue is pagination in  data-table. I am showing 10 (showing Active records only in the list ) records  per page, for example 11 records are there in listing, data-tables shows pages count as Previous, 1, 2 and Next so its fine for now.

Suppose I changed the status of anyone record in that list to In Active, now the records in the listing are 10 only. So my issue is it shows the pagination as same as Previous one without any record (11th record) i.e. Previous, 1, 2 and Next.

If I click on number 2 it will navigate to 2nd page without any records and it shows "No records found", That was my big issue with Bootstrap data-tables.

Comment: can you add you html file here or please provide the js fiddle link what you tried?

Comment: Hey, post your code here!

Comment: table =   $("#searchUser").DataTable({
       "language": {
         }, 
      bFilter: false,
          ajax: {
             "data": function(){
                  $('#searchUser').DataTable().ajax.url(
                   //Some action
                  );
               }
          },
          serverSide:true,
          "columns":[
                     { // render
                        "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                  return data.status;
                                }
                      ]
                  },
         });